# File entity with no error field causes Burzum/Filestorage to treat file as not-present?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Currently in the middle of a major upgrade and overhaul so I'm not sure if there is something wrong on my side or not? Currently running CakePHP3.6 with PHP7.2 and the Burzum Filestorage plugin version 2.0.0.

In that plugin, in [FileStorageBehaviour line 61](https://github.com/burzum/cakephp-file-storage/blob/2.0/src/Model/Behavior/FileStorageBehavior.php#L61) is the following method:

```
protected function _isFileUploadPresent($entity) {
    $field = $this->getConfig('fileField');
    if ($this->getConfig('ignoreEmptyFile') === true) {
        if (!isset($entity[$field]['error']) || $entity[$field]['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

However, the $entity at this point looks something like this:

```
object(ArrayObject)#692 (1) {
  ["storage":"ArrayObject":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["file"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["tmp_name"]=>
      string(14) "/tmp/phpAEzNZD"
      ["name"]=>
      string(13) "image.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

As $entity['file']['error'] is not set, the if(!isset($entity[$field]['error'] bit fails and false is returned.

Not sure if $entity['file']['error'] should always be set, or if the if statement should be something like if( isset($entity[$field]['error'] && $entity[$field]['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) ?

Comment: Well, why is there no error field? If it's missing something is wrong with the data that is passed to the method. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php The fail is correct.

Comment: Thanks! I looked deeper into this and it turned out I handle upload errors myself but fail to pass them to the plugin.